# Removing first X elements from array

Tags: c, pointers

I have an array named arr of size 1024. So basically I want to delete the 1st X elements of the array. How would I do that? This is what I am thinking:
Make a pointer pointing to the 1st value of the array (arr[0]). Do pointer arithmetic to take it to the X'th element of the array. Then  set the arr[0] to the pointer p, which will effectively remove the first X elements? Will this work?
Or is there an easier way to remove the first X elements of the array?

Comment: How is the array allocated?

Comment: How is the array allocated (stack or heap)?

Comment: @Sam You have been faster by 10 seconds. This must be because I've typed 10 more characters :)

Comment: What do you mean by *delete*? Does this mean you just want to be able to iterate over it, skipping the first X elements? If it's allocated on the stack, I don't think you can change its size; you need to either create another array or allocate a suitably-sized block of memory.

Comment: What is `p` that you mentioned?

Comment: The array is a global string. It is initialized using: char arr[1024]

Comment: @Sam: Yes I just want to skip over the first X element, so that the next time arr[0] is called, it returns the value of arr[X].

Comment: If you have used malloc for the array && if you have "shared" the original array pointer with somebody else, then you need to be careful when you change the array starting location. So, can you clarify whether this pointer is malloc'ed and or shared? Is all array indexing done by getting the starting array address and adding an offset to it? Also, when you change the array location, do you need to free the old memory back to the system (not possible in a stack allocn)?

Comment: This is not malloc'ed. All array indexing is done by adding an offset to it yes. I am not looking to do any memory allocations, as it is not allowed yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the array is global it will exist in memory until your program terminates. But this won't stop you declaring a pointer which points to one of its internal items, and using this pointer as the start of your array. With your notations: `char* p = arr + X;` This way `p[0]` will be equal to `arr[X]`, `p[1]` to `arr[X + 1]`, and so on.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am trying to do. I tried to do *p = arr, then p++ till it reaches the Xth item. But after this I am stuck on how I will set arr[0] to be the p

Comment: @nonion: you can't set `arr` to be `p`, just use `p` instead of `arr` in the rest of your code. Incidentally, you don't need to do `p++` X times - just do `p=arr+X;`

Comment: @nonion Do this: char* p = arr + X; This way p[0] will be equal to arr[X].

Comment: Ah I was thinking of doing this. I just made modifications to the function to use the point p instead of using the array directly. Thank you!!

Comment: @nonion since you seem to be in school and doing some homework, i suspect there is more to what you are asking. check out the circular buffer answer - i believe that will be what you will eventually need.

Answer (score 3):

check out the function memmove, if you can.  This is a great way to move a chunk of memory quickly.

Comment: I can't use this function :\ Memory allocation/editing is not yet taught in my class. This is only a smaller part of my assignment which I am stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

If `arr` is declared as `char arr[1024];` then you cannot.

If `arr` is declared as `char * arr = (char *)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));` then: `arr += 3`

Or declare it as `char do_not_use_this_name[1024];` then use `char * arr = do_not_use_this_name + 3;`

Comment: What is the need of casting `malloc` here, its return type will automatically be converted to `arr`'s type

Comment: not sure. i sort of remember C used to require a cast, but these days it sure doesn't. may be old school thing?

Comment: @randomsrting yes , `malloc` doesn't require . it ain't an error though. `malloc` basically returns a void pointer so when it allocates....  its return type is converted to that of variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat `arr` as a circular buffer. However, you cannot access it like a regular array anymore. You would need an interface.

```
char arr[1024];
int pos = 0;
int size = 0;

#define arr(i) arr[(pos+(i))%1024]

void append (char v) {
    arr(size++) = v;
}

void remove_first_x (int x) {
    pos = (pos + x) % 1024;
    size -= x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the pointer `X` units and treat that as the start of the array:

```
int arr[1024]; // could be other type as well

...

int *p = arr;
...

p += X; // x is the number of units you want to move
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement to not use `memmove` and to cause `arr[0]` to return the result of `arr[x]`, you could do something like this:

```
char arr[1024];
int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
char* source;
char* destination;
char* arr_end = arr + arr_size;

//Initialise the array contents

for (destination = arr, source = arr + x; source < arr_end; ++source, ++destination)
    *destination = *source;
```

Keep in mind that this is just *shifting* the contents of the array backwards by X. The size of the array is still 1024.

Note that this will not do anything with the remaining X elements at the *end* of the array. If you want to zero them, you could subsequently do something like this:

```
for (; destination < arr_end; ++destination)
    *destination = 0;
```

Comment: I think that I have solved the problem by just appointing a point to the array, then for the rest of my code, use the pointer instead of the array directly. however, I'll test out this code that you posted above and if it works better than the pointer solution I got, I'll use yours. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've only used this implementation because of my understanding of your requirements. In general, I recommend the use of pointer arithmetic because it's simpler and more efficient.